# How do I fill in the blanks of a main class, drink/drinkinbox/drinkincyclinder/etc

Tags: java, switch-statement, program-entry-point

I have all the classes set except the main, and this is what I need to do:

```
case 'A':   //Add Drink
           System.out.print("Please enter a drink information to add:\n");
           inputInfo = scan.nextLine().trim();
/***********************************************************************************
***  ADD your code here to create an object of one of child classes of Drink class
***  and add it to the drinkList
***********************************************************************************/
           break;
         case 'C':   //Compute Total Prices
/***********************************************************************************
***  ADD your code here to compute the total price for all drinks in the list.
***********************************************************************************/
           for(int i = 0 ; i < drinkList.length(); i++) {
               drinkList[i]
           }
           System.out.print("total prices computed\n");
           break;
         case 'D':   //Search for Drink
           System.out.print("Please enter a drinkID to search:\n");
           inputInfo = scan.nextLine().trim();
/***********************************************************************************
***  ADD your code here to search a given drinkID. If found, set "found" true,
***  and set "found" false otherwise.
***********************************************************************************/
            if (found == true)
             System.out.print("drink found\n");
            else
             System.out.print("drink not found\n");
           break;
```

Here is the code from my drinkparser:

```
Drink myDrink = null;
    if(word[0].equals("Cylinder"))
    {
        int one = Integer.parseInt(token4);
        double two = Double.parseDouble(token3);
        int three = Integer.parseInt(token5);

        myDrink = new DrinkInCylinder(token2, two, one, three);

    }
    else
    {
        double one = Double.parseDouble(match3);
        int two = Integer.parseInt(match4);
        int three = Integer.parseInt(match5);
        int four = Integer.parseInt(match6);

        myDrink = new DrinkInBox(match2, one, two, three, four);
    }
    return myDrink;
}
```

And this is the method in both drinkInBox and drinkInCylinder:

```
public void computeTotalPrice()
{
    volume = (int)(Math.PI*(radius * radius * height));

    totalPrice = volume * unitPrice;
}
```

What do I need to do to fill in these blanks? I'm thinking the compute total price should be something like:

```
for(int i = 0 ; i < drinkList.length(); i++) {
               drinkList[i] //I don't know how to call the computeTotalPrice method for any particular index of drinkList, I can't say .drinkInCylinder or drinkInBox because there isn't a way to tell which object type it is
```

Comment: Your `drinkList` is a `List` of what?

Comment: The program asks if you want to add drinks, compute prices, search for a drink, or list them. drinkList stores each one as you type them in. They have to be written in this format:For a cylinder drink,

shape/drinkId/unitPrice/radius/height

For a box drink,

shape/drinkId/unitPrice/height/width/depth

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could do this

```
for(int i = 0 ; i < drinkList.length(); i++) {
    if(drinkList[i] instanceof DrinkInBox)
        (DrinkInBox)drinkList[i].computeTotalPrice();
    else if(drinkList[i] instanceof DrinkInCylinder)
        (DrinkInCylinder)drinkList[i].computeTotalPrice();
}
```

However, this is a bit redundant and it seems pretty obvious that you could have a super class, let's say `Drink`. You should define the `computeTotalPrice` on that class. `DrinkInBox` and `DrinkInCylinder` would both inherith from `Drink`.

By the way, following Java naming conventions, classes should start with capitalized letter.

Comment: Yes! Drink is the superclass, DrinkInBox extends Drink, as does DrinkInCylinder. Sorry they do I just forgot to capitalize. If we have a super class, but it doesn't have a computeTotalPrice method, does it inherit that method from either of the child classes?

Comment: The problem with putting one in the Drink class is the methods are different for each one, one computes volume via cylinder logic, the other as h*w*l, using variables that are only in either of those classes

Comment: You define it in the super class, but you override it in the child classes. When you call that method from the super class, he knows which one to execute.

Comment: By define it do you mean just:

public abstract void computeTotalPrice();

Comment: If so then won't I still need to specify which one to run it through? If I only use
    (Drink)drinkList[i].computeTotalPrice();

How will it know whether it's a cylinder or box?

Comment: `public abstract void computeTotalPrice(){}` will do it. No, you don't. That's the power of inheritance. From your `ArrayList` of `Drink`, it will know if it is a `DrinkInBox` or `DrinkInCylinder` and execute the respective function.

Comment: You can create a small example with a `ParentClass` and a `ChildClass`. Create a `example` method and override it in the `ChildClass`. Then create an object like this: `ParentClass c = new ChildClass();` and execute the `example` method, and you'll see the child's method is executed.

Comment: Okay, it's almost working, one last issue: It says that method computeTotalPrice in the type Drink is not applicable for the arguments (object). Any idea what I need to do?

Comment: Probably you're calling the `computeTotalPrice` with a parameter? That method should take no parameters at all, so it should be called like `computeTotalPrice();`